# sorting columns using particular words in c#

Tags: c#

i have a table with a column named size which will have values big,medium and small. wat i want is i want to sort this column in such a way that all rows with size big should come first, then rows with size medium and finally rows with size small.
is there a way by which i can achieve this?

edit: it is a data table which i add to a dataset.

edit: wat if the initials of the words, in this case b,m and s, are not in alphabetical order. in that wat am i supposed to do coz i have another application as well where i'll be required to sort a column having value High, normal and low.

Comment: @Pratik As Greg has stated, you need to give more detail in order to get valid answers, I don't believe its a database table because the answer is so simple

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]; 
DataView dv = new DataView(dt); 
dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction; //sortexpression will be fieldname direction will be ascending descending
GridView1.DataSource = dv;
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Have a look at this article: Express Yourself with Expression-based Columns

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx

OF COURSE IT WORKS!

```
    DataSet myDs = new DataSet();
    DataTable myDt = new DataTable("Table1");

    myDs.Tables.Add(myDt);

    myDt.Columns.Add("Size", typeof(string));
    myDt.Columns.Add("Ranking", typeof(int), "Iif((Size)='Large', 1, Iif((Size)='Medium', 2, Iif((Size)='Small', 3, 4)))");

    DataRow myDr1 = myDs.Tables["Table1"].NewRow();
    DataRow myDr2 = myDs.Tables["Table1"].NewRow();
    DataRow myDr3 = myDs.Tables["Table1"].NewRow();
    DataRow myDr4 = myDs.Tables["Table1"].NewRow();

    myDr1["Size"] = "Large";
    myDr2["Size"] = "Medium";
    myDr3["Size"] = "Small";
    myDr4["Size"] = "Large";

    myDt.Rows.Add(myDr1);
    myDt.Rows.Add(myDr2);
    myDt.Rows.Add(myDr3);
    myDt.Rows.Add(myDr4);

    DataView myDv = new DataView(myDt);
    myDv.Sort = "Ranking";

    ultraGrid1.DataSource = myDv;
```

And that is the code that proves it.

Comment: i don't think it will allow me to do what i want.
anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Voting down solves the problem of having too much rep, since you loose points for down votes. You should restate as "Voting down does not solve 'most' problems".

Answer (score 1):

Map big, medium, small to an enum in the correct order and sort on that.
Any other answer will require more information as asked for in the comments.

Comment: why map to a enum? just sort on the column size

Answer (score 1):

If this is really as masqueraded T-SQL question, you could either use `UNION` (as proposed by Lukasz), or you could use a few `WHEN ... THEN` constructs in your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY WHEN size = 'big' THEN 2 WHEN 'medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This *might* also work in ADO.NET, but I have *not* tested it:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort =
    "WHEN size = 'big' THEN 2 WHEN 'medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
```

---

**EDIT:** David points out, that in your specific case (big, medium, small), the alphabetical sort order matches the expected ordering. In this special case, you can simply do:

```
ORDER BY size
```

Or in ADO.NET:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "size";
```

Comment: why not just sort on size column big, medium and small (b,m,s)

Comment: David, honestly, I didn't spot that fact! I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution (and if these values are unlikely to change), just order by the 'size' column, since the *big*, *medium* and *small* words are in alphabetical order :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in sorting algorithm of the `DataView` (which is where you'd do actual sorting, not in the `DataTable` itself), this isn't possible, strictly speaking; there is no support for "custom" sorting, which is what you'd need. The sorting capabilities of the `DataView` are actually surprisingly limited, and (IIRC) it isn't even a [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sort (since it uses [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx), which is documented as unstable).

Your only real option (from a GUI perspective) is to use a data display control that provides custom sorting capability, like the DevExpress XtraGrid.

Answer (score 0):

After edits by OP, it has become (somewhat) clear that we are dealing with a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

One approach to sorting the rows of a `DataTable` according to a "mapped value", would be to use its [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method to retrieve several arrays (one for each value) of rows:

```
List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();
rows.AddRange(oldTable.Select("size = 'Big'"));
rows.AddRange(oldTable.Select("size = 'Medium'"));
rows.AddRange(oldTable.Select("size = 'Small'"));
```

If needed, the rows can be imported into a fresh `DataTable` with the same schema:

```
DataTable newTable = oldTable.Clone();
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
    newTable.ImportRow(row);
}
```

This approach is definitely not very efficient, but it's probably about the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try a switch statement.

```
Switch(var) 
{ Case "Big":
//Append to TextBox1
//Or add to var1[]
break;
  Case "Small":
//Append to TextBox2
//Or add to var2[]
break;
  Case "Medium":
//Append to TextBox3
//Or add to var3[]
break;
}
```

**EDIT:** Sort into txtbox's or var[]'s, does this go-round make more sense?

Comment: I thought it was obvious the first time... Apparently not.